# How do I stop iTunes from defaulting as browser for pdf files?

Tags: pdf, itunes

I don't know if I'm using the correct terminology, but I'm trying to view a PDF file sent to my email and it goes to iTunes's 'books' and I'm not able to open it or view it, or copy to another file to open it.

What do I do? I don't want PDF files to go to iTunes.

Comment: I dont use itunes , but having tried checking you default application for pdf ?

Comment: windows or mac?

Answer (score 1):

Download the attachment from your email to your desktop or any place you prefer. Once it's downloaded, Right click the file and choose open with. At the bottom of that box there should be an option to choose a default program to use. Select whichever program that will work and hit ok.

EDIT:
On a Mac, Option + Click on the file and go to "get info." There is a section in there that has "open with..." and you follow the same steps. At the bottom of the open with box there should be a button to apply to all files also. Be sure to hit that.

Comment: @victor23k - I will from now on. My apologies

Comment: @victor23k - Macs now have right clicks too. All macs post 2007 have shipped with a two button mouse.

Comment: Just a small correction: Control-click (not option-click) acts as a right-click.